# How can I get the vertex labels of an existing graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

For example, if there is a graph

```
g = CompleteGraph[5, VertexLabels -> {1 -> "v1", 2 -> "v2", 3 -> "v3", 4 -> "v4", 5 -> "v5"}]
```

How can I later get the vertex labels of this graph? Something like:

```
RetrieveVertexLabels[g]
```

> {{1,"v1"}, {2,"v2"}, {3,"v3"}, {4,"v4"}, {5,"v5"}}

I know similar functions exist for `VertexList` / `EdgeList`.

Thanks!

Comment: `VertexLabels /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexLabels]` might work.

Comment: Indeed, thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List @@@ PropertyValue[g, VertexLabels]
```

> {{1, "v1"}, {2, "v2"}, {3, "v3"}, {4, "v4"}, {5, "v5"}}

or

```
List @@@ Options[g, VertexLabels][[1, 2]]
(* same output *)
```

Comment: This one is great, thanks!